# What halachos flow from there being a Jewish nation and not just a religion?

Tags: halacha, am-yisrael-jewish-nation

[Rabbi Mordechai Becher at Aish.com](https://www.aish.com/jl/jnj/jn/Is-Judaism-a-Race-Religion-Family-or-Nation.html) says that we are a nation united by our common heritage. So two Jews could see themselves as members of a nation.

A more limited definition of the relationship between two Jews would be to say that they practise the same religion.

Are there halachos that follow only from being members of a nation and would not be in force just because we have the same religion?

For example, does the concept of כל ישראל ערבים זה בזה – every Jew bears the responsibility of the mitzvah observance of every other Jew - flow from nationhood or common religion?

**EDIT** Following the useful responses, another way of expressing the question is "are there any halachos that are better categorised as national in origin rather than Bein Adam le-Chavero?"

Comment: It is not so clear what you confront - nation vs religion? Judaism uses both - some Mitzvos say רעך or עמיתך meaning "observant like you" (aka religion), some only base on national origin (בני ישראל) like marrying or Trumah or else.

Comment: @AlBerko Answer?

Comment: If you define religion as a formal relationship between Man and the Divine, then the _Mitzvot she-Bein Adam la-Maqom_ (and their _Halakhot_) would be the religious aspect of Judaism, and the _Mitzvot she-Bein Adam le-Chavero_ would the national aspect: Just like secular nations have laws regarding property, endangerment of human life, and marriage, so does Judaism through the _Mitzvot she-Bein Adam le-Chavero_.

Comment: The title says "flow" and the Q "follow" - which one is right?

Comment: The Korban Tamid is an obligation on the Tzibbur. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I was expecting an answer that quoted Rav Avrohom Yitzchak Hakohen Kook.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from pointing you to specific *halakhot* in a piece like Shulhan `Arukh, I think the underlying philosophical difference (which significantly impacts one’s approach to Halakhah) is: if Judaism is strictly a religion than those who are lax about their Judaism are less Jewish perforce. But, if we are foremost a family, we continue loving one another despite our differences and do as much as we can to keep people in the fold.

For a specific Halakhic outcome, R’ Uri Sherqi is [of the opinion](https://ravsherki.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=530:530530-530&catid=22&Itemid=100512) that the wine of a Jew who doesn’t keep Shabbat is permitted assuming he served in the IDF loyally.

Note: R’ Sherqi is a talmid of R’ Zvi Yehuda Kook (among others).

Answer (score 0):

Possible answers:

1. **Judaism is not a religion by itself.** Your differentiation stems from the commonly wrong translation of the Hebrew word "דת" as "religion". In Biblical Hebrew דת means "a Law". G-d didn't give us a religion, He gave multiple laws for the Jewish nation, and G-d didn't divide it into "religious laws' or "national laws".  While we do distinguish between Mitzvos between Man and G-d and Mand and his fellow, but they all came from the same source.
2. Maybe you mean "**Mitzvos that apply to someone because he's religious or because he's a Jew**": Yes, many Mitzvos Between Man and his fellow in the Torah use languages of "רעך, עמיתך, אחיך etc" *implying* that they should be applied not to any Jew but those who follow the Torah like you / are observant and Kosher Jews. Other Mitzvos do not make this distinction and must be applied to all national Jews.
3. "**Improving the religion vs improving the Nation**": Many Rabbinical decrees focus on improving specifically the Jewish nation, not the religion, like many Halochos of partnership in the Gemmorah - how Jews should coexist in peace. Those decrees can be called "purely national", if you like.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The question was difficult to formulate. Following your answer and the comments, I think that the deep idea I have is whether there are any halachos that are better categorised as national in origin rather than Bein Adam le-Chavero. I shall try to edit that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

[This article at tora.co.il](http://www.tora.co.il/shiurim/shvat/important_isra.doc) asks related questions. The second question provides examples of mitzvos which come from being members of a nation and would not be in force just because we have the same religion.

Why did G-d create Am Yisrael as a nation and not just a religion?

Why, in addition to the mitzvot between individual Jews, and between man and G-d, does the Torah call for a framework of a national land,[1] language,[2] army,[3] political system, and even coin?[4]

References:

[1] See the article "The Centrality of Eretz Yisrael to Judaism" regarding the mitzvot of aliya, living in and building Eretz Yisrael, et al.

[2] Ibid; Sifre and Rashi on Dvarim 11,19; Y. Shab.1,3; Gra on Y.D. 245,10; Mishna Brura 307,63; Igrot Moshe Ev.H. III 35; Chatam Sofer (resp. Ev.H.11); See extensively in Kuntres Safah LaNe’emanim, by R. Baruch HaLevy Epstein (author of the Torah Tmima), Warsaw, 5653, and my article, “Hadibur Bilshon Hakodesh”, Talilei Orot 2 (5750) pp. 87-101.

[3] Rambam, M’lachim Umilchamotehem 5,1; Shulchan Aruch  Ch.M.426,1  and Or.Ch. 330,6; Resp. Nodah B’Y’huda II Y.D. 161.

[4] See Rambam, Hil. M'lachim at length.